# expected a component class, got [object Object]

Tags: react-native

I get an error with this code. However, changing  to react-native's  removes the error. Can you use div with react-native? If not, why is this error so obscure...?

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactNative = require('react-native');
var {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} = ReactNative;

let Auto = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { value: 'Ma' }
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="fuck-react">
        Blah blah blah
      </div>
    )
  }
```

});

Comment: In React-Native, View takes the place of Div so better use View!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No you cannot use div tag in react-native. Since, react-native is based on JSX syntax which are automatically dispatched to native components by abstract Dom parser. you can get your answer here:https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html

Also, react-native is upadated to new version that is 0.29 , you probably should ignore old ECMA script and use new ECMA script for javascript syntax. Since, react-native uses reactjs for its javascript so better learn from here: http://reactjs.net/guides/es6.html

Comment: there is newer version available for react-native : 0.29 .Check here: [upgrade to latest](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Does packer automatically find files with extension jsx? What's the version have to do with this question? Does 0.29 provide better errors?

Comment: React-native application is mainly based on syntax, so with the upgrading in react-native version the change in syntax is priotrized. So, we should adapt the change of JSX syntax while developing application.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of DIV use View.

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
       <Text>Blah blah blah</Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use  in react native. Use native component instead.

```
<View>
  <Text>text text text</Text>
</View>
```

Do not forget to import before with:

```
import {
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be using ReactJS component in a React Native App. I accidentally installed a component with `<div>` tags in React Native project.